# How can I prevent or allow running a query based on a value stored in $_SESSION

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to allow user input to be stored in my database only if the user's `$_SESSION` contains a non null value.

This is my current code:

```
$verifiedd = $_SESSSION['verified'];

if (is_null($verified)) {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO feedbacks (feedback) VALUES(?)');
    $feedback = $_POST['feedbackeris'];
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $feedback);
    $stmt->execute();
    $_SESSION["error"] = $error;
    header("location: feedback.php"); //send user back to the login page.
    exit();
} else {
    $_SESSION["error"] = $error2;
    header("location: feedback.php"); //send user back to the login page.
    exit();
}

$stmt->close();
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223572/discussion-on-question-by-mr-d-fpv-how-can-i-prevent-or-allow-running-a-query-b).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your php has a few issues, see the comments below:

```
<?php
// you're wanting to access $_SESSION but havent called `session_start()`
$verifiedd = $_SESSSION['verified'];    // $_SESSSION should be $_SESSION with 2 S in the middle
                                        // $verifiedd should have only one d


if(is_null($verified)){ // this doesnt match the variable name above (because above has 2 ds)
    // also, this allows the insert if the user is NOT verified, the oppositee of what we want
    $feedback = $_POST['feedbackeris'];
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $feedback);
    $stmt->execute();
    $_SESSION["error"] = $error;  // the "$error" variable is not defined anywhere before this assignment
    header("location: feedback.php");
    exit();
}
else {
    $_SESSION["error"] = $error2; // the "$error2" variable is not defined anywhere before this assignment
    header("location: feedback.php");  // no need to write these 2 lines in both conditions, can be done once at the end
    exit();
}

$stmt->close(); // $stmt is only defined in the `if` above, if the `else` gets hit, this will cause an error
```

You might rewrite this code something like:

```
<?php
session_start();

if(!is_null($_SESSION['verified'])){
    $feedback = isset($_POST['feedbackeris']) ? trim($_POST['feedbackeris']) : null;
    if (!$feedback) {
        $_SESSION['error'] = 'Some error about feedback cant be empty';
    } else {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO feedbacks (feedback) VALUES(?)');
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $feedback);
        $stmt->execute();
        if ($stmt->error) {
            // probably dont want to expose this to the end user FYI
            $_SESSION['error'] = htmlspecialchars($stmt->error);  
        }
        $stmt->close();
    }
}
else {
    $_SESSION['error'] = 'Some error about not being a verified user';
}
header("location: feedback.php");
exit();
```

Comment: Thank you! it is working it was my bad as well on auth page it was $_SESSIOn['verified'] also very good explanation damn i hope one day I will get to this stage ... :D white jealous :P

Comment: @MrD.FPV any time, no worries, not too long ago I was right where you are ;) Happy coding.